# Why does a question marked as duplicate get more views than the original?

Tags: discussion, editing, exact-duplicates

As an example case, there's [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2227773/167197), slated to be deleted, which is marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1643681/167197). Even though the latter one is more general and has been around longer, it has attracted fewer views. Why is this? Is it because the older question has a poorer title so it's harder for a user to tell what the question is immediately about?

Additionally, since the duplicate looks like it's going to be deleted, should the original question be edited in some way to attract more attention, to attract the sort of users who instead found the duplicate post?

Comment: I went ahead and fixed the title of the older one to make it more descriptive.  My suspicion is that this is the major distinction between the two questions.